# Как сделать так чтобы этот Javascript код запускался от нажатия кнопки в html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Нужно чтобы этот скрипт запускался с кнопки, если оставить всё просто так, то он запускается при открытии сайта, а мне нужно чтобы человек нажимал на кнопку на сайте и запускался этот скрипт. Подскажите пожалуйста!

```js
 var words = [
        "макака",
        "компьютер",
        "яблоко",
        "апельсин",
        "мандарин",
        "телефон",
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

    var answerArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        answerArray[i] = "-";
    }

    var remainingLetters = word.length;

    while (remainingLetters > 0) {
        alert(answerArray.join(""));
        var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры.");
        if (guess === null) {
            break;
        } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
            alert("Пожалуйста, введите только одну букву");
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
                if (word[j] === guess) {
                    answerArray[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

alert(answerArray.join(""));
alert("Отлично! Было загадано слово-" + word);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var words = [
  "макака",
  "компьютер",
  "яблоко",
  "апельсин",
  "мандарин",
  "телефон",
];

function startGame() {
  var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

  var answerArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "-";
  }

  var remainingLetters = word.length;

  while (remainingLetters > 0) {
    alert(answerArray.join(""));
    var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры.");
    if (guess === null) {
      break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
      alert("Пожалуйста, введите только одну букву");
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
        if (word[j] === guess) {
          answerArray[j] = guess;
          remainingLetters--;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  alert(answerArray.join(""));
  alert("Отлично! Было загадано слово-" + word);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startGame()">Начать</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

В HTML

```
<button class="play">Играть</button>
```

В JS

```
const play = document.querySelector('.play');
// Получаем кнопку
```

И обернуть весь код в

```
play.addEventListener('click', function () {
// .. ваш код ..
});
```